# Do notation for monad in function returning a different type

Tags: haskell, monads, option-type

Is there a way to write `do` notation for a monad in a function which the return type isn't of said monad?

I have a main function doing most of the logic of the code, supplemented by another function which does some calculations for it in the middle. The supplementary function might fail, which is why it is returning a `Maybe` value. I'm looking to use the `do` notation for the returned values in the main function. Giving a generic example:

```
-- does some computation to two Ints which might fail
compute :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int

-- actual logic 
main :: Int -> Int -> Int
main x y = do
  first <- compute x y
  second <- compute (x+2) (y+2)
  third <- compute (x+4) (y+4)
  -- does some Int calculation to first, second and third
```

What I intend is for `first`, `second`, and `third` to have the actual `Int` values, taken out of the `Maybe` context, but doing the way above makes Haskell complain about not being able to match types of `Maybe Int` with `Int`.

Is there a way to do this? Or am I heading towards the wrong direction?

Pardon me if some terminology is wrongly used, I'm new to Haskell and still trying to wrap my head around everything.

**EDIT**

`main` has to return an `Int`, without being wrapped in `Maybe`, as there is another part of the code using the result of `main`as `Int`. The results of a single `compute` might fail, but they should collectively pass (i.e. at least one would pass) in `main`, and what I'm looking for is a way to use `do` notation to take them out of `Maybe`, do some simple `Int` calculations to them (e.g. possibly treating any `Nothing` returned as `0`), and return the final value as just `Int`.

Comment: The point is that these calculations should result in a `Maybe` as well, or if not, you can use a `return`.

Comment: Not sure what you're referring to, `compute` or `main`? Either way, `compute` already returns a `Maybe` value, while `main` is intended to definitely return an `Int`, hence no `Maybe`. In other words, one of the calculations in `main` might fail, but at least one should pass which guarantees that `main` has an `Int` return value.

Comment: but the idea of a `Monad Maybe` is to see `Maybe`s as "potentially failing" computations. So here you make a "chain" of potentially failing computations, and return `Just result` in case it succeeds, and `Nothing` otherwise. If you are sure `compute` will always return an `Just _`, then why does it have the signature `Int -> Int -> Maybe Int`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well the signature is in essence wrong. The result should be a `Maybe Int`:

```
main :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
main x y = do
  first <- compute x y
  second <- compute (x+2) (y+2)
  third <- compute (x+4) (y+4)
  return (first + second + third)
```

For example here we `return (first + second + third)`, and the `return` will wrap these in a `Just` data constructor.

This is because your `do` block, implicitly uses the `>>=` of the `Monad Maybe`, which is defined as:

```
instance Monad Maybe where
    Nothing >>=_ = Nothing
    (Just x) >>= f = f x
    return = Just
```

So that means that it will indeed "unpack" values out of a `Just` data constructor, but in case a `Nothing` comes out of it, then this means that the result of the entire `do` block will be `Nothing`.

This is more or less the convenience the `Monad Maybe` offers: you can make computations as a chain of *succesful* actions, and in case one of these fails, the result will be `Nothing`, otherwise it will be `Just result`.

You can thus not at the end return an `Int` instead of a `Maybe Int`, since it is definitely possible - from the perspective of the types - that one or more computations *can* return a `Nothing`.

You can however "post" process the result of the `do` block, if you for example add a "default" value that will be used in case one of the computations is `Nothing`, like:

```
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

main :: Int -> Int -> Int
main x y = fromMaybe 0 $ do
  first <- compute x y
  second <- compute (x+2) (y+2)
  third <- compute (x+4) (y+4)
  return (first + second + third)
```

Here in case the `do`-block thus returns a `Nothing`, we replace it with `0` (you can of course add another value in the [**`fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) as a value in case the computation "fails").

If you want to return the first element in a list of `Maybe`s that is `Just`, then you can use [**`asum :: (Foldable t, Alternative f) => t (f a) -> f a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum), so then you can write your `main` like:

```
-- first non-failing computation

import Data.Foldable(asum)
import Data.Maybe(fromMaybe)

main :: Int -> Int -> Int
main x y = fromMaybe 0 $ asum [
    compute x y
    compute (x+2) (y+2)
    compute (x+4) (y+4)
]
```

Note that the `asum` can still contain only `Nothing`s, so you still need to do some post-processing.

Comment: Thanks, your comment that refers to it as a chain of successful actions made it clearer to me, and I realize I actually am going in the wrong direction. What I intend is not for it to be a chain of actions, but a series of computations (which any might fail, but one is guaranteed to pass), and returning the first out of the series that passed. In essence, what `main` is doing is abstracting away the possible failures and choosing the first that succeeds, so that a definite `Int` value can be used elsewhere when it calls `main`. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @lookarpthestars: you could use `asum` for that, like `asum [compute x y, compute (x+2) (y+2)]`, which will return the first `Just` in the list, but this is still a `Maybe`, since it is possible that *all* computations fail.

Comment: See: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:asum

Comment: Sweet, this comment along with the part you added after the edit gives me something to work from. Appreciate the concise answer.

Comment: @lookarpthestars to your first comment, *no*,  main is *not* "choosing the first that succeeds". only if all three computations succeed it returns a Just (with the sum of three results). otherwise it returns Nothing. so it tries to run all of them (one after another, but *all* of them) and then combine all the results.

Answer (score 3):

Willem's answer is basically perfect, but just to really drive the point home, let's think about what would happen if you could write something that allows you to return an int.

So you have the `main` function with type `Int -> Int -> Int`, let's assume an implementation of your `compute` function as follows:

```
compute :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
compute a 0 = Nothing
compute a b = Just (a `div` b)
```

Now this is basically a safe version of the integer division function `div :: Int -> Int -> Int` that returns a `Nothing` if the divisor is `0`.

If you could write a main function as you like that returns an `Int`, you'd be able to write the following:

```
unsafe :: Int
unsafe = main 10 (-2)
```

This would make the `second <- compute ...` fail and return a `Nothing` but now you have to interpret your `Nothing` as a number which is not good. It defeats the whole purpose of using `Maybe` monad which captures failure safely. You can, of course, give a default value to `Nothing` as Willem described, but that's not always appropriate.

More generally, when you're inside a `do` block you should just think inside "the box" that is the monad and don't try to escape. In some cases like `Maybe` you might be able to do `unMaybe` with something like `fromMaybe` or `maybe` functions, but not in general.

Answer (score 1):

I have two interpretations of your question, so to answer both of them:

### Sum the `Maybe Int` values that are `Just n` to get an `Int`

To sum `Maybe Int`s while throwing out `Nothing` values, you can use `sum` with [`Data.Maybe.catMaybes :: [Maybe a] -> [a]`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:catMaybes) to throw out `Nothing` values from a list:

```
sum . catMaybes $ [compute x y, compute (x+2) (y+2), compute (x+4) (y+4)]
```

### Get the first `Maybe Int` value that's `Just n` as an `Int`

To get the first non-`Nothing` value, you can use `catMaybes` combined with [`listToMaybe :: [a] -> Maybe a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:listToMaybe) to get `Just` the first value if there is one or `Nothing` if there isn't and [`fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base/docs/Data-Maybe.html#v:fromMaybe) to convert `Nothing` to a default value:

```
fromMaybe 0 . listToMaybe . catMaybes $ [compute x y, compute (x+2) (y+2), compute (x+4) (y+4)]
```

If you're **guaranteed** to have at least one succeed, use `head` instead:

```
head . catMaybes $ [compute x y, compute (x+2) (y+2), compute (x+4) (y+4)]
```